# How does one express "On the way to or from school"? Is 上下班 okay?

Tags: grammar

What is the proper way to say, "On the way to or from school (suppose from home)..." For example: "On the way to or from school students like to look through the cars windows."

When referring to: going to, coming from work you use the expression 上下班 but I think my teacher said you cannot use  上下学. The expression 放学回家 means going back from home after school finishes.

Can anyone tell me the right expression?

If I want to give good point to an answer how can I do it? Last question I didn't know how.

Comment: "上下学" seems to be a common enough phrase, why can't it be used?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 上下學 in daily conversation. I would say it looks a bit weird in an essay.

Answer (score 4):

> One the way = 途中

On the way to school - 上学途中

On the way to work - 上班途中

On the way home - 回家途中

On the way home from school - 放学回家途中

On the way home from work - 下班回家途中

We say 上下班 because it is short for "上班, 下班"

We usually say  "上学, 放学" not "上学, 下学".

Although not the logical shortened form, people still use the term 上下学 instead of '上放学' because '上' matching '下' better than '上' matching '放'.

*you can replace 下班 with 放工*

Comment: to give point to an answer, you can up vote it by click on the upward arrow on the left of the answer. If you accept the answer is the correct one, you can click on the check mark  on the left of the answer

Comment: Using  all caps in your post title  is usually not a good idea https://danieltitus.com/blog/advertising/237-why-all-caps-is-usually-a-bad-idea

Comment: You can also edit posts (questions &/or answers) to make them looks more aesthetically pleasing & commenting on your own answer is not likely to grab OP's attention.

Answer (score 2):

I never did that!

On the way to or from school，
在往返学校的路上，

students like to look in the cars parked along the road.
学生们总是爱往停在路边的汽车里看。

(There may be something worth stealing!)
（车里也许会有值得盗取的东西！）

Comment: '在往返学校的路上' is a neat one with home implied.

Answer (score 2):

上下学 sounds stilted to my ear(or even wrong), though it's fairly understandable. It might be a regional matter. (I'm from mainland China. )

I would probably put 在上学和放学的路上, 在上学和放学的途中, 在学校和家往返的路上 or 在学校和家往返的途中. It's a bit long. I can't think of a neat way to express it off the top of  my head.